# Can I prevent enter key press from calling change event of Input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, onchange, keyup

change event is required for other scenario but that shouldnt get triggered on enter key press.

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Ljwa10es/1/

##### Sample Input

```
const inp = document.querySelector("#inp");
inp.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);
inp.addEventListener("keyup", keyupHandler);

function changeHandler(e) {
      console.log(e.target.value)
}

function keyupHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log("Enter key pressed")
    }
}
```

change event is required for other scenario but that shouldnt get triggered on enter key press.

Comment: yes, `preventDefault` on `keyPress` of `Enter`

Answer (score 0):

```
  const inp = document.querySelector("#inp");
  inp.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);
  inp.addEventListener("keyup", keyupHandler);

  function changeHandler(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  function keyupHandler(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
              e.preventDefault();
        }else{
              console.log("Enter key was not pressed")
        }
  }
```

You would have to stop the keyup function from triggering the change function by using the preventDefault method.

Comment: change handler got executed even if call e.preventDefault() in keyup handler.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljwa10es/2/

Comment: @DINESHKUMARK the change handler gets called after the textbox loses focus, so there's no way to detect if the user leaves the textbox after pressing the enter key or not. He could've pressed enter key and any other key before leaving the textbox. So, it's my suggestion to use the keyup handler in conjunction with the keydown handler to call the function that you're intending to call.